# Distance of moving objects

Tags: android, algorithm, gps, accelerometer

I hope to develop an android base app for purpose of tracking a moving train and a moving car. I want to get the distance using global positioning system.

1. How accurate is global positioning system for this purpose?
2. How to do it?
3. Is there any other way to track the both moving objects and the distance between them?

Comment: The problem was little bit confusing.As i understood, you want the GPS locations of two objects(Car & Train) and to get their distance.right?
So you need two devices(Preferably two phones) in both objects.
If this is correct you have to find an efficient way to communicate between those two.
And yes GPS is the most accurate technique for this kind of scenario.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1% - 2% for distances over 5km (Note: for distance the RELATIVE accurace is relevant, while the abosulte position is worse; e.g 3m on average)
2. Use a position only if their speed attribute is faster than walking speed.
3. GPS is the best, most practical and very accurate for this task. Even a calibrated tachometer does not reach the 1% accuarcy. Some systmes combine wheel ticks, with GPS calibration for a even more acuraty distance mesurement.